# Is it a bad idea to store nested map(key-value) pair in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, hashmap

How does ElasticSearch stores map of key-value pairs considering that fields are not analyzed. Is storing array of objects instead of map a better Idea?

Comment: it depends from your purposes. Please take a look here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Storing key/value pairs helps if data schema you are trying to store is unknown and potentially unbounded.